# Unit testing HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to unit test some of my web services. For this, I want to assert some of my `HttpResponseMessage`s. For this, I'm doing:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void LoginTest()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(_accountController.Login("testuser", "testpw")); //CODE STOPS RUNNING AT THIS LINE
    Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode, "User unable to log in with correct login info");
}
```

Where `Login` is a method like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Login(String userName, String userPassword)
{
    try
    {
        if (userName == null)
            return NotFound();
        //Logging in user etc.
        return Ok();
    }
    catch
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

However, the test always return as failed, even though the `Login()` returns `Ok()` when I debug. No apparent errors or exceptions, however, when I debug the test, the output shows things like (I've excluded lines that just show what's `Loaded` or `Unloaded`):

```
The thread 0x1190 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Web.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TestFailedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestFramework.TestFailedException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll
The thread 0xaec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' in System.ServiceModel.dll
The program '[9936] vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4084] TanulmanyiRendszer.Admin.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

My guess is that this is not the way you're supposed to convert the `IHttpActionResult` to `HttpResponseMessage`. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if using `IHttpActionResult` as return types for actions then check if the actual type being returned is a proper derived type. No need for checking `HttpResponseMessage` as that is a concern of the framework

```
[TestMethod()]
public void LoginTest() {
    var response = _accountController.Login("testuser", "testpw") as OkResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(response, "User unable to log in with correct login info");
}
```